# attempting to boot from Win 10 install DVD to re-install, orange screen with white lines

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I have an older Dell Precision T5400 with a RAID controller setup for RAID 0 with 2 SAS drives.  One of the drives failed, so I ordered a replacement online, was able to get the same drive.

Replaced the drive, went into RAID controller config, deleted the array, created it, and all is happy there.  It sees both drives and has a volume created with RAID 0 for them.

I booted from a live Linux disc and ran Gparted and setup an ntfs parition using the entire space.

I then booted from the Win 10 install DVD and when I do so I get an orange screen with white vertical lines and a cursor.

An online search suggests that this is Bitlocker and most places suggest entering your Bitlocker password and hitting enter.  I tried that, but I'm thinking the replacement drive I ordered must have been used by someone else who was using Bitlocker so I have no idea what the password would be.

Given that I'm trying to re-install Windows on this drive, is there any way to get around this?  I thought setting up the partition with the live Linux disc would have done it.  Apparently not.

Anyone else run into this and figure out a way around it?

UPDATE: Here's an image of the screen I'm seeing; this isn't my image just one I found online but it matches what I'm seeing.

[image: orange screen with white lines]

UPDATE: Went back into gparted using a live linux boot disc, and remove the partition and yet still the Win 10 install CD goes to this orange screen.  All I can think is that somehow there's a bitlocker presence on the replacement drive and removing the partitions didn't get rid of it.

Comment: If you had no paritions, and just made a single basic NTFS one, then I can see no way BitLocker is involved.  Can you provide a screenshot/picture of the orange screen you're seeing?  Exactly when are you getting this orange screen?  Have you tried re-downloading and re-writing your Windows installer to USB again (perhaps to a different USB drive)?    Regardless of that, I'd suggesting removing all existing partitions from the drive, and then just let the Windows 10 installer make them for you, as it usually also needs to make a couple other partitions for boot, etc.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've added an image I found online which shows the same thing I'm seeing.  I'm getting this screen when booting from the Windows 10 install DVD as I indicated.  I'm not using a USB drive, I'm booting from a DVD which I just re-burned and I get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of orange screen by copying all ttf font files from another computer to the usb stick and now I can see the screen, but in the screen after there is an error 0cx0000098 present...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).